# Empty Rooms and Production FX

Tags: production-sound

Hi everyone-

Got a shoot coming up and I could sure use some advice. The short takes place in a house that is up for sale, so it's devoid of any furniture. Moving blankets on C-stands going to be of any use? I'll be using a Schoeps CMC6/MK41 Hyper.

Also, some scenes are free of dialogue, just a lot of movement and rummaging through boxes. Would you recommend the same mic for the PFX?

Cheers-
Max

Answer (score 2):

Moving blankets in C stands will certainly help. Also take special note to the corners of the rooms on the ceiling. I used to put a bunch of old towels and sheets in a sack or material bag and gaffa tape or hook them onto the corners - doing that for all corners can make a big difference in dampening reverb (I am assuming that's what you are trying to achieve).

I use the same mic for location dialogue and action sound but perhaps in a studio you have the luxury of choosing mics with particular qualities over others rather than on location. Just (as I'm sure you do) be sure to get a good clear signal for whatever you are focusing on - dialogue or action.

Can I ask what is PFX? I have not come across that before and a google search gave no results.

Good luck!

Comment: PFX = Production Sound FX - sound effects recorded on set during filming.

Comment: To further that thought, in my experience its always been classified that PFX = sound effects that happened during a scene and are married to production (which are split out by the dialogue editor to PFX tracks), whereas specifically-recorded, isolated on-set sound effects recordings are called Wildtracks or Wildtakes.  Just my 2 cents ;)